# CakeEmail setting recipient's name

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

does anyone know if it is possible, and if so, how to set recipient's name when sending an email through CakeEmail class? For now we have it working as the following:

```
$Email = new CakeEmail();
$Email->from(array('me@example.com' => 'My Site'))
    ->to('you@example.com')
    ->subject('About')
    ->send('My message');
```

Where as in the to field, we would like to include recipient's name to bypass spam filters.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean? Something like: `->to('you@example.com' => 'Your Name')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set it the same way you set the from email using an array:-

```
$Email = new CakeEmail();
$Email->from(array('me@example.com' => 'My Site'))
    ->to(array('you@example.com' => 'Recipients name')
    ->subject('About')
    ->send('My message');
```

Answer (score 2):

It helps to read the documentation and/or look at the source code
https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Network/Email/CakeEmail.php#L441

All of the above clearly state that you can pass a second param:

```
...->to($email, $name)->...
```